# Reasons of working slowly and solution of that

Tags: c#, regex

here is my function with using regex. it's working corectly but it's taking tags very slowly.
I think it's searching html code character by character.So it works slowly. Is there any solution of working slow.

```
string s = Sourcecode(richTextBox6.Text);
        // <a ... > </a> tagları arasını alıyor.(taglar dahil)
        Regex regex = new Regex("(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)</a>");
        string gelen = s;
        string inside = null;
        Match match = regex.Match(gelen);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            inside= match.Value;
            richTextBox2.Text = inside;
        }
        string outputStr = "";
        foreach (Match ItemMatch in regex.Matches(gelen))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ItemMatch);
            inside = ItemMatch.Value;
            //boşluk bırakıp al satır yazıyor 
            outputStr += inside + "\r\n";
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = outputStr;
```

Comment: Don't use Regular Expressions. Use a proper HTML parsing library like Html Agility Pack. You'll see a tenfold increase in speed.

Comment: any different idea why it is taking tags slow?

Comment: this could slow it down if there are lots and lots to append. `outputStr += inside + "\r\n";`

Comment: I love these questions.... Refer to.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 for HTML regex parsing

Comment: Arghhhh! Yet another "Parsing HTML with regex problem" question! Does no one search any more? The top hit here for "regex html parsing" finds [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) as the top result.

Comment: I provided a sample of another way to get information from HTML in another one of your questions yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20984718/1967692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble with parsing HTML is that it isn't an exact science. If it was XHTML that you were parsing, then things would be a lot easier.
Because HTML isn't necessarily well-formed XML you will come into lots of problems trying to parse it.
It almost needs to be done on a site-by-site basis.

You should not parse HTML using Regex.(Although you can use compiled Regex in your above code, to make it a bit quick.)
Regex is not build for parsing HTML. You can use a third-party library for parsing HTML which are built specifically for this purpose.
[List of HTML Parsing Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653357/html-parsing-libraries-for-net)
If you don't want to use 3rd party libraries, then you can use the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` for this purpose.
You can also use [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/), it uses HTML agility pack, but has extended support for jQuery
Then there is [Majestic-12 HTML Parse](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php), which is very quick.
You can also use TidyNet.Tidy to convert the HTML to XHTML, and then use an XML parser.

Check the following [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045.aspx) on how improper usage of Regex can degrade performance.

Answer (score 1):

Change outputStr to a StringBuilder, if you are appending very many items this will increase your speed.  As already mentioned parsing HTML with a regex might be an issue (depends a lot on your input).